# Documentation on ASP.Net Flow

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know if there's any documentation/resources the describes the complete process flow of an ASP.Net application? Looking for something that describes IIS handing off the HttpRequest and the usage of the PageParserFilters and such.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much information can be found on Microsoft's ASP.NET application lifecycle overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx

And there's more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: These provide a decent amount of information but I'm hoping to get a bit further down to better understand where PageParserFilter and similar classes fit into this flow.